# Filehandle STDOUT reopened as FILE only for input

Tags: perl

Giving the following (medieval age) code:

```
# Method to save and close the Standard output(STDOUT) and after to redirect the
# STDOUT in the log file of the step
sub doSomething{
    open(_OLDOUT, ">&STDOUT") or Error('001', "open", "Standard OUT", __PACKAGE__, $ERRNO);
    close(STDOUT) or Error('001', "close", "Standard OUT", __PACKAGE__, $ERRNO);
    open(STDOUT, ">".$self->{logFile}) or Error('001', "open", "Standard OUT", __PACKAGE__, $ERRNO);
}
```

I get an error at the first `open` command. The error is formatted with a function `Error` which gives me this message:

```
ERROR-001: System command <open> failed in file Standard OUT for module core::AnotherModule. Reason: !
```

Before this error I get an warning:

```
Filehandle STDOUT reopened as FILE only for input at d:\Path/FirstModule.pm
```

This is the line of code (from FirstModule.pm) that generates it :

```
open FILE, "<".$file or Error('005',$file,__PACKAGE__,$ERRNO);
```

Of course this is just a chunk of the code behind it.
I searched on the internet and at first sight it seems that `STDOUT` is closed earlier and when I am creating a handle to a file it is considered as `STDOUT`. What options do I have? Would it be safe to open manually the `STDOUT` to avoid the error?
P.S. The whole program is also multi-threading.

Answer (score 7):

At your Perl program startup, file descriptor 0 is `STDIN`, and opened for input. And file descriptors 1 and 2 (`STDOUT` and `STDERR`) are opened for output. It is perfectly legal to close these standard filehandles (and occasionally some good reasons to do so).

When you open a new filehandle, Perl might use a new file descriptor, or it might reuse an old one that had been previously closed. If you closed a standard filehandle, and again, there are many good reasons why you might have done that, Perl might reuse the standard file descriptor for the new filehandle.

One check that Perl performs when it opens a filehandle and assigns a standard file descriptor is to check the mode of the filehandle with the expected mode of that file descriptor, and to warn when the modes don't match. This is to keep you from doing something silly with the standard filehandles that might be hard to debug further downstream

```
$ perl -Mdiagnostics -we 'close STDIN;open STDIN,">foo"'
Filehandle STDIN reopened as FOO only for output at -e line 1 (#2)
    (W io) You opened for writing a filehandle that got the same filehandle id
    as STDIN.  This occurred because you closed STDIN previously.
```

but also issues the warning when you are doing something else legally and correctly

```
$ perl -Mdiagnostics -we '
my $input = <STDIN>;
close STDIN;
open my $fh, ">foo";
print $fh "your input was $input";
close $fh'
Filehandle STDIN reopened as $fh only for output at -e line 4 (#1)
    (W io) You opened for writing a filehandle that got the same filehandle id
    as STDIN.  This occurred because you closed STDIN previously.
```

This is just a warning.

To suppress it, you can redirect the standard filehandles to `/dev/null` (or on Windows, to `nul`) when you close them. That is, instead of

```
close STDIN;
...
open FOO, '>foo';         # might get reassigned to fd 0
```

say

```
close STDIN;
open STDIN, '<nul';       # /dev/null on POSIX systems
...
open FOO, '>foo';         # won't get reassigned to fd 0
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanations and for the examples! The problem which I have is not that warning, but the error. I thought somehow they are interfering one with another. Do you think that the warning and the stuff that it's happening there is related ( or a cause) to the error?

Comment: What is in $self->{logFile}? Is it a valid and writeable filename?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yes it is!